# How to fix a white screen on mapbox in flutter

Tags: flutter, mapbox

```
        *Here is the new error i encounter*

  I tried using a Mapbox i followed exactyly this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oc1mktx0Zn8&t=22s on Youtube
```

But when it is time for me
    to run the app it display a white screen only here is the code for the map:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Leaflet Maps')),
        body: new FlutterMap(
            options: new MapOptions(
                center: new LatLng(35.22, -101.83), minZoom: 10.0),
            layers: [
              new TileLayerOptions(
                  urlTemplate:
                  "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/zion21/ck20raa6m3p341cmrjsmd5555/wmts?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiemlvbjIxIiwiYSI6ImNrMjBlMHFtMjB4NDQzbXE4N3FqcGVibzEifQ.9d-UxqgnIdB1WeDHKfwp-A",
                  additionalOptions: {
                    'accessToken':
                    'pk.eyJ1IjoiemlvbjIxIiwiYSI6ImNrMjBxYWczaDA0ZjAzaXBnY3ZhdjM3ZzAifQ.rY3J57etwhIiJ_0yqfmWPQ',
                    'id': 'mapbox.mapbox-streets-v7'
                  })
            ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: what does the command-window show when you run flutter run?

Answer (score 0):

You need add a unique id to floatingActionButton

```
Widget button(Function function, IconData icon) {
    return new FloatingActionButton(
      heroTag: "id1",
      onPressed: function,
      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      child: Icon(
        icon,
        size: 36.0,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: i already tried that and I kinda give up on the Google_maps haha. i Switch to mapbox i got a new error

Comment: i just update my question. kindly check it out and see what is the possible solution to my code